# How can I access a CSV Flatfile in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, dom, csv

Please I need help on accessing data in a CSV file that is stored locally on my app.

What I want to do is when a user clicks the search input on the app, it should display data from the locally stored CSV file.

I tried the popular root but it can only access a .js file, I need one that can read a CSV file.

Please help!!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script
```

>

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileReader API to access a local CSV file:

```
function readCSV()
 {
 var fileString = arguments[0].target.result;
 return fileString
 }

with (new FileReader)
 {
 var files = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
 onloadend = readCSV;
 readAsText(files, "utf-8");
 }
```